# Qt Build w/ DLLs Included

Tags: qt, dll, build

In Qt when I build a project it creates the executable but it doesn't include the necessary DLLs. Is their some option I can turn on to do this for me?

Comment: Is there a problem with running/testing the app or do you need to make a static link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are referring to deploying your application. If you build with static linking to Qt, you won't have to distribute Qt DLLs but you will have a large executable. You may have to compile the Qt library yourself to get static libraries.

Dynamic linking will require you to copy the appropriate Qt DLLs with your application. Some build environments may have an option to help with this. If you mention what your development tool chain and platform is in the question, somebody may be able to help with specifics.

Qt has some documentation related to deployment [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/deployment.html).